# Hyperledger Composer - Deploying to a multi-organization Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm currently learning to setup a multi-org Hyperledger Fabric network with Composer.

I've started with the byfn sample from HL Fabric documentation, changed the names of the orgs and added an extra organization, changed the referenced scripts, and so on. Using the sample as help, I'm able to create the channel, join all the peers from my 3 orgs, setup the anchor peers.

What I'm doing next is moving on to the Composer tutorial on how to deploy for a multi-org Fabric. And I've successfully created and imported the business network cards and installed the bna on to the peer nodes for each organization.

The next step would be to run the composer identity request command to retrieve certificates, and this is the place I'm stuck.

```
composer identity request -c PeerAdmin@test-network-manager -u admin -s adminpw -d andreim
```

with the following result:

```
Error: failed to request identity. Error trying to enroll user and return certificates. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]
```

Does anybody have any ideas of what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CA containers started for the 3 Orgs?

The connection refused error suggests not.

The byfn script from the default Fabric repo does not start the CA for the orgs.  The [Composer Tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/deploy-to-fabric-multi-org) you are referring to directs readers to use a different repo and branch to get specific versions of the `byfn.sh` and `eyfn.sh` script (plus a few other config files).

To continue, building on the work you have already done, you could create CA containers based on `.yaml` files in this repo https://github.com/mahoney1/fabric-samples/tree/multi-org/first-network - you would need to modify these new yaml files for your org details, with particular attention to the TLS_KEYFILE.

Alternatively you could first follow the MultiOrg tutorial as-is to get a feel for the task before working on your modified network.

Comment: You were right. I was mistakingly using another fabric repo. Once I realised it and started with the right one, it worked up until trying to start the Fabric network. I'm getting a strange error: Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Parameter must be a ProposalResponse Object. Any idea what's happening?